# `elif` not recognized

Tags: python, flow-control

I'm trying to use flow control

```
if x == `Lala´:
    print(`lalalala.´)
    elif != `lala´:
        print (`lololol.´)
```

The problem I have is a syntax error with - e - from `elif`
and when I skip four spaces at the front or four spaces at the back the problem stills. When I put the `elif` in the same line as the `if` the program doesn't execute the `elif`.

Comment: It should be at the same indentation level as the `if`.  Note that when the `if` condition is met, nothing else will be done.   You've also got a fair amount of syntax errors - you've got "smart" quotes in there, the `elif` only has half of a conditional, the two conditions don't make a lot of sense (on is matching `Lala`, the other is saying not `lala` - looks like a case error), you could probably just use an `else`, etc.

Comment: Please upvote helpful answers and accept the one that helps you best.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few problems.

1. Whitespace is meaningful in python. The `elif` needs to be at the same level as the `if`
2. Your `elif` statement is malformed.
3. Your quote marks are non-standard.

It should be:

```py
if x == 'Lala':
    print('lalalala.')
elif x != 'lala':
    print ('lololol.')
```

Answer (score 1):

- You seem to have quotations marks that are copied out of a text/document file format (e.g. word/pdf). These should be ''.
- Remember that `elif` needs to be on the same indentation level as `if` in python
- You need to have a **full** condition inside the `elif` - currently you have `!= 'lala'` - you need to have the full condition = `x != 'lala'`
- Make sure to initialise `x` as well - although I'll assume you have done this further up in your code

Like this:

```py
if x == "Lala":
    print("lalalala.")
elif x != "lala":
    print ("lololol.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'nothing'
if x == 'Lala' :
    print ('lalalala.')
elif x != 'lala' :
    print ('lololol.')
```

You forgot to compare x in your elif statement.

Answer (score 0):

First you have mixed up your quotes. In both the `if` and the `print` you start with a "``" and close with a "´". Programming languages usually don't take typographical quotes (Perl 6 is the only exception I know).
If you are using WordPad or Microsoft Word to write code, switch to a programmer editor that doesn't change your quotes. Always use the same character for beginning and end of a text, either `"` or `'` (or even `"""` or `'''` for multi-line strings).

Then your `elif` needs to be on the same level with the `if`: they are different branches of the same flow control. With its current indentation you have an `elif` without a matching `if`.

You are also missing the variable in the `elif` comparison: to what do you want to compare "lala"?

Finally you should initialize  `x` before comparing it.

```
x = "..."

if x == "Lala":
    print("lalalala.")
elif x != 'lala':
    print ('lololol.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having here is that it is not formatted properly and your **ELIF** statement does not have the same indentation level, bear in mind that an **ELIF** statement should always be on the same level as a regular **IF** statement. If the **IF** statement is satisfied before the **ELIF** statement, your program will not continue to execute any further validation statement.

Recall that the **ELIF** statement means "else-if" meaning that if the initial IF statement is not satisfied, the program will continue to validate the variable through the **ELIF** statement. Treat it like it is an **ELSE** statement, and give it the same indentation level as an **IF** statement. Also remember that whitespaces are important in Python, so pay particular attention to this as well, I have included the revised code below. Do not forget to include the variable **X** in your **ELIF** statement.

So instead of this:

```
if x == `Lala´:
    print(`lalalala.´)
    elif != `lala´:
        print (`lololol.´)
```

Do this instead:

```
if x == 'Lala':
    print('lalalala.')
elif x != 'lala':
    print ('lololol.')
```